# Check if file crontab runs

Tags: linux, debian, php, cron, crontab

I've set up crontab tasks to be executed every min.

```
* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php
```

I see its log in var/log/syslog file:

```
Jan  3 15:14:01 clearthefog CRON[26579]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php     /home/admin/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
Jan  3 15:15:01 clearthefog CRON[26623]: (root) CMD (sudo /usr/bin/php /root/scrapers/terra_plf/terra_swap_api.php)
```

Yet, **nothing is written into DB** as the file `terra_swap_api.php` should do. Any suggestions why? Any way to check if the file is actually executed?

When I run the same script in CLI it work perfectly: php terra_swap_api.php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply sudo in cron, since it will ask for the sudo password. You'd have to setup passwordless sudo for that command.

Since the php file is in the /root dir (take note it's a security concern), you could install the crontab as root (`sudo crontab -e`) and put the line in there (without sudo).

If your script doesn't require root privileges, you could run without sudo, but you'd have to move the files to a readable location, since /root is owned and restricted to the root user.